# The dollar ($) prefixed field is not valid for storage

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have two classes:

```
public class Client
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OtherData> Other { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class OtherData
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of documents of Client.

I'd like to update a item on `Other` based on it's id.
So I have this code.

```
Expression<Func<Client, bool>> filter = x =>
            x.Id == id
            && x.Other.Any(t => t.Id == idOther);

var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Client>()
            .Set(x => x.Other.ElementAt(-1), dadoBancario);

await _collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

But when I run this code, I get this error:

> Command findAndModify failed: The dollar ($) prefixed field 'Other.$' in 'Other.$' is not valid for storage.. MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
>              at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)

I'm using Cosmos DB.
Is this some compatibillity issue?

Or there is another way that I can go?

Comment: `x.Other.ElementAt(-1)` does not look right to me. I'd expect this to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in Linq2Objects, and be shocked if a Linq2Sql implementation allowed it.

Comment: It does not. The driver converts to mongodb dialect correct. In fact, cosmo db api still does not support it. It's a duplicate question.